# Moving sandbox version back to spring release

Tags: apex, deployment, appexchange, sandbox, release

Recently the sandbox that I used to load my app exchange product is upgraded to summer 17 , this has become a problem for me as I am unable to load the app in to the sandbox. The app works with spring 17 sandbox. Is there a way that Salesforce can revert back to the previous version of my sandbox i.e sprint 17?

I do not want to make a change to the code now to install in Summer 17 env due to tight deadlines and inability to modify code at this point of time. Any idea how I can overcome this?

Comment: You think you have tight timelines now, wait till production is updated and your code breaks. Its semi-unusual that an app will break simply due to a sf scheduled release. Maybe if you let us know the issue someone may be able to help....Also, if it is an issue with the App i am sure the vendor would like to know. Have you reached out to them?

Comment: It is something related to using visual work flow in apex. I am trying to help a person figure this out and also I am curious to know a solution. The app will be fixed before the production environment is upgraded to summer 17. But it seems like salesforce cannot move to previous release and app has to be fixed. Thanks for your insights!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't rollback a sandbox. The only thing you can do is refresh the sandbox from production to get it back to Spring 17. Unfortunately, this also means you lose any customization you've done in the sandbox and any data you've created.

I'd also add that Summer 17 release is going to be pushed to orgs in about a month, so you should resolve any issues with Summer 17 soon.

Comment: @sfdcBat To add to the 2nd paragraph here, as an AppExchange app creator, you need to ensure that your app is functional in the upcoming version or your customers are going to have a broken application when Summer 17 is released and they try to use your app. Part of release management is planning for these release windows and testing your app in the new release versions.